# How to resolve "unable to execute xfce4 session" error in X2go client?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine

I am trying to connect to Linux VM graphical desktop using X2go client. I followed standard procedure mentioned on learn.microsoft.com(link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/data-science-virtual-machine/dsvm-ubuntu-intro#x2go).

**Virtual Machine Specification:** Azure VM (Ubuntu 18.40 LTS))

**Client OS:** Windows 10

**Description of error:**

*Error Previously Resolved:*

After following the above mentioned procedure, I encountered an error "Bash:x2golistsessions command not found" on x2goclient software installed on my client machine. This was resolved by installing packages x2goserver and x2goserver-xsession on VM using Azure Powershell as mentioned in X2go documentation(https://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/doc:installation:x2goserver).

*New Error Encountered:*

However, after resolving the error mentioned above I am getting another error, "unable to execute xfce4 session" on x2go client software on my client machine. I tried installing xfce4 on my client machine using Bash on ubuntu on windows by installing xfce4 using sudo apt install command. But, the error continues to persist.

Kindly provide resolution. I am new to this field and not know much so please help me out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server side configuration:

1. sudo apt install xfce4
2. sudo apt-get install software-properties-common(for Ubuntu 14.04 and above)
3. sudo add-apt-repository ppa:x2go/stable
4. sudo apt-get update
5. sudo apt-get install x2goserver x2goserver-xsession
6. service x2goserver status(If it is loaded and running its ok otherwise use service x2goserver start to run it)

Client side configuration:

1. sudo apt install xfce4(for windows based OS use bash on ubuntu on windows or powershell)
2. Install x2go client(https://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/doc:installation:x2goclient) as you install regular software downloading setup file and installing it.
3. Follow the prescribed instructions to fill in the host address and username. Select the session to be xfce from the drop down list. Hit OK.

Voila!You are done!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Run `apt install xfce4` on the server.

Answer (score 0):

As my test, you just need to download the X2Go client for your client machine OS. For example, my local machine is Windows 10. So I download the X2Go client for Windows [here](https://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/doc:installation:x2goclient).

And then I install the client on my local machine with the default setting. Run the client and configure the session like this:

[image]

The first time it failed with time out. And the second time it works fine. So you do not need to install the server on your local machine. It's installed Data Science VM with Ubuntu 18.40 LTS.

Comment: I thank you for your reply but the connection is not working in my case even though I followed same steps as you.